# What is the efficient way to compute the derivative of Rectified linear unit?

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning

here is my fucntion

```
def ReLU(x):
    y=x * (x > 0) 
    return y
```

What is the efficient way to compute the derivative ?

```
def DReLu(x):
    yp=1. * (x > 0)
    return  yp
```

l got this problem when l used this derivative

```
yp=1. * (x > 0) # the problem is here RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater yp=1. * (x > 0)
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve, what the problems are, what parts currently inefficient are etc?

Comment: @Cleb  RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater yp=1. * (x > 0)

Comment: Ok. What is `x`? does it contain numbers? It might be caused by NaNs in `x`.

Comment: x : number between 0 and 1 and l don't have NaN value in x

Comment: Mmmh, then I don't know. NaNs in the array were the only way I could reproduce this error.

Comment: It works fine for me when I give a number for x, are you just passing a float or an array?

Comment: yes it's an array of 784 float values between o and 1